# Regex for sequence of characters that is not equal to

Tags: regex

I have a URL pattern that looks like this: `^foo\/(?P<prefix>[a-z]+)\/bar\/$`.

I need the sequence of characters in the middle to be different than another sequence of characters, let's say `ab`.

`foo/somestring/bar/` and `foo/abcde/bar/` should match, but `foo/ab/bar/` should not.

I've come as far as `^foo\/(?P<prefix>(?!ab)[a-z]+)\/bar\/$`, but that doesn't match `foo/abcde/bar/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot about restricting the negative lookahead value until the `/`:

```
^foo\/(?P<prefix>(?!ab\/)[a-z]+)\/bar\/$
                      ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU5lM4/1)

If you use `(?!ab)`, it forbids matching values that start with `ab`. Adding the trailing boundary makes it disallow anything that equals that value inside the negative lookahead.